# how to make messages, where users can send php, javascript or html without running it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I dont want code, that users send each other to run on my server.
How to make them see that code in messages, and that code not to run?

Comment: Let me initialise mind reader so I can see what's your project about and I'll be right with you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you probably mean html code & scripts.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($html); ?>
```